# Marking a pytest.Item subclass

Tags: pytest

I'm writing a test suite which loads tests from external (non-Python) files, in a similar manner to [the YAML example in the documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/example/nonpython.html#a-basic-example-for-specifying-tests-in-yaml-files). However, I cannot work out what should be have `pytest.mark.foo` called on to mark a specific item as "foo". Obviously I can't use it as a decorator as is always done in the documentation (there's no single function to decorate!), but I was assuming it would be plausible to do something similar to `yield pytest.mark.foo(YamlItem(name, self, spec))`, but this does not work. Is there any way to mark such an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Node.add_marker` function (which is a superclass of `pytest.Item`):

```
def add_marker(self, marker):
    """ dynamically add a marker object to the node.

    ``marker`` can be a string or pytest.mark.* instance.
    """
```